# Nginx error: FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream ... "

Tags: php, nginx, yii2, centos

I have a yii2 advanced template application running on centos 9 with nginx and php 8.1. Have setup the vhost configuration like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    root /home/lamtab/xp-app-main/app/appadmin/web;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    access_log "/var/log/nginx/mydomain.com.access.log";
    error_log "/var/log/nginx/mydomain.com.error.log";

    location / {
       try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
   location ~* \.php$ {
                # With php-fpm unix sockets
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
                include         fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
        }
    fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 90;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 90;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 90;
}
```

The domain's error log reports

FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream ... "

and nginx's error log reports

index.php" failed (13: Permission denied)

Any clues?

Comment: Hi Lampros. Would you make an attempt emptying your `location` block as follow : `location / {}`. As you define the default file with the `index` directive, the `try_files` seems to be useless.

Comment: The user which runs the Nginx process needs read access to the file and **every directory** in the pathname `/home/lamtab/xp-app-main/app/appadmin/web/index.php`

Comment: I gave to nginx user ownership of the folder. I even tried 777 rights to the index.php

tried emptying the location block and I only get the forbidden error

Comment: According to @RichardSmith remark, you shoud still try the `namei` command to `/home/lamtab/xp-app-main/app/appadmin/web/index.php` with nginx user and then check the rights through the entire path (file and **folders**). See https://serverfault.com/a/639215/987415

Comment: all files and folders in the path are owned by the nginx user

Comment: Ok, but there is obvioulsy a lack of read rights somewhere :( Excuse me for insisting, but a `namei -l /home/lamtab/xp-app-main/app/appadmin/web/index.php` would point it out.

Comment: It seems you were correct. I added read access to /home/lamtab folder and there is no 403 error now, but 404 instead. That has probably nothing to do with nginx conf though

Comment: Good point :) And if you explicitely address `/index.php` in a browser, does it fail with 404 ?

Comment: It's all good now. Thank you both for your help

Answer (score 1):

In my case I killed several hours for nothing, turns out I just had to restart php8.1-fpm service in ubuntu 22.04. Try it maybe it'll help.My conf file looked like this

```
server {
   listen   80 default_server;
   root /home/user/your_project/public/;
   index index.php index.html index.htm;
   access_log /home/user/your_project/nginx-access.log;
   error_log /home/user/your_project/nginx-error.log;
   server_name localhost;

location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri index.php =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
   }
}
```

Comment: Can confirm, same with Ubuntu 22.04 here. Restarting php-fpm fixed it, sometimes it's just too simple :).